# Como dar acceso a ciertos equipos mediante htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

tengo la siguiente pregunta.

Eh creado un panel de administración para mi sitio web, y solo quiero darle acceso a ciertos equipos.

Estoy probando con las siguientes líneas de código

```
Deny from All
Allow from 186.35.50.90 (IP PUBLICA DE EJEMPLO)
```

Pero resulta ser que dicha IP creo que corresponde al entorno de red, es decir que si me conecto desde mi celular a la misma red, puedo ver la pagina web y quiero que solo tenga acceso el quipo es decir 1 solo computador o  1 computador y 1 celular, como puedo darle acceso a esos equipos a traves de la ip ? y como puedo saber la ip de dichos equipos, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Las directivas `Allow` y `Deny` son obsoletas. Usa `Require ip 186.35.50.90`. Tu IP la encuentras [en google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip)

Comment: Pero resulta ser que si pongo esa ip, cualquier persona que se conecte a mi red puede tener acceso al panel de administración y solo quiero que 1 equipo tenga ese acceso, es posible lograr eso?

Comment: Lo inclui en el htaccess que esta en la raíz de la web

Comment: Inclúyelo en el htaccess donde esta tu página de administración.

Comment: Si ya lo eh hecho, pero como te mencionaba si pongo la ip que me arroja Google, si yo entro desde mi computadora puedo ver la página, si conecto mi celular a la misma red igual puedo ver la pagina, entonces yo solo quiero que la computadora tenga acceso a la web y ningún otro dispositivo, a pesar de estar en la misma red

Comment: Entiendo, como a ojos del servidor la IP pública es la misma... tendría que ser por autenticación de usuario.

Comment: No es como si hubiera una manera de diferenciar dispositivos solo con su IP. Tendrás que decantarte por alguna alternativa que te permita acceder a más información del cliente.